# How to install 3rd party libraries using bower (not all files)?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, gruntjs, bower

In Web application (AngularJS), using 18 third party libraries. Whole application size is 50 MB, in that bower_components occupies 48 MB. Need to reduce the size of the application. Application is only client concerned app. I am Struggling for 2 days. Is there any way to restrict the bower install in bower.json. I need only .js, .min.js files and .css files. Please help me

Thanks in Advance.

**bower.json**

```
{
"name": "eshopingChannel",
"version": "0.0.0",

"dependencies": {
"angular": "1.6.1",
"angular-resource": "1.6.1",
"angular-cookies": "1.6.1",
"angular-messages": "1.6.1",
"angular-sanitize": "1.6.1",
"angular-animate": "1.6.1",
"angular-material": "latest",
"lodash": "~2.4.1",
"angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
------
------
------
-----
},
"devDependencies": {
"angular-mocks": "1.6.1",
"angular-scenario": "1.6.1"
},
"resolutions": {
"angular": "1.6.1"
}
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: you will need to learn gulp for that...